# Server - Client connection between android app and a server

Tags: java, android, sockets, connection

I'm developing a Java Server Aplication and an Android Aplication and my android app need to send and receive data from/to server (Bidirectional), for example my Android App need to Login to the server and the server need to know who is logged in.
Wich protocol do you recommend me to do this kind of program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in this situation you can use HTTP protocol for several reason. First of all you can reach your server even if it is behind a firewall or something like that.
Second using HTTP you can send XML or JSON data widely used in android.
The only limitation you have is the HTTP protocol is a synchronous protocol so you send and wait for the answer.
Using HTTP you can use your existing server architecture and you can wrap your business layer with a Webservices so that you can expose your services.
If you need that server can contact your app you can use you can use Google Cloud Mesaging.

Answer (score 1):

Use Http request (get or post request) to communicate with a server.
You have to use a thread or an AsyncTask to perform your request or the execution fails from Api 11+.
I attach an example of http request that receives an xml:

```
    import org.apache.http.*;
    [..]

    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.d("XMLParser-getXmlFromUrl", "UnsupportedEncodingException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d("XMLParser-getXmlFromUrl", "ClientProtocolException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("XMLParser-getXmlFromUrl", "IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```